# Blender crashes constantly since v2.80 on Linux when using Nouveau driver

Tags: linux, system

I started using Blender at v2.80 and it is constantly crashes ever since, after approximately 2-3 mins after startup. I use Arch Linux with `nouveau` driver. Blender crashes either with Eevee and Cycles engine chosen. Every time at some point Blender freezes my whole desktop env. (with mouse cursor) and then successfully crashes, OR (approximately with 1:1 chance) do not unfreezes desktop and gets me hard rebooting machine.

Last time I called blender with `--log <file>` and `--debug` options and saved project file, but there was no files except project file in the working directory. The last lines Blender returned to my terminal that I could see after the crash scrolling all the way up were:

- a lot of `nouveau: 0x<8-digit hex number>`
- `` blender: ../libdrm-2.4.101/nouveau/pushbuf.c:723: nouveau_pushbuf_data: Assertion `kref' failed. ``
- `Aborted (core dumped)`

I see bug is highly likely related with `nouveau`.

Comment: The *Nouveau* open source driver does not work with CUDA, you have to use the proprietary Nvidia Drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Nouveau drivers aren't officially supported, the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) state that the official Nvidia drivers have to be installed when using one of their graphics cards.

> **NVIDIA**: GeForce 400 and newer, Quadro Tesla GPU architecture and newer, including RTX-based cards, **with NVIDIA drivers** (list of all [GeForce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce#GeForce_400_series_and_500_series) and [Quadro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Quadro#Quadro_FX_(with_CUDA_and_OpenCL,_but_no_Vulkan)) GPUs)